# Using other fonts caused xdvipdfmx:fatal: Invalid font: -1

Tags: fonts, xdvipdfmx

I'm an new user of Arch Linux and TeXLive 2021, I update all my packages from `tlmgr` just now on. When I tried to use `xelatex` to compile the tex file below

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\begin{document}
    Here are some lines to read. 
\end{document}
```

I got the error of

```
xdvipdfmx:fatal: Invalid font: -1
```

I paste the whole log here: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/FJzRCZJjC6/

When I first use `xelatex -no-pdf main` to get `main.xdv`, and use `xdvipdfmx` to compile my `.xdv` file, it output

```
$ xdvipdfmx -vv main.xdv
<FONTMAP:/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map><FONTMAP:/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap/kanjix.map><FONTMAP:/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/ckx.map>DVI Comment:  XeTeX output 2021.09.01:2042
main.xdv -> main.pdf
<AGL:texglyphlist.txt><AGL:pdfglyphlist.txt><AGL:glyphlist.txt>[1</usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/libertinus-type1/LibertinusSerif-Regular.pfb@9.96pt<NATIVE-FONTMAP:/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/libertinus-type1/LibertinusSerif-Regular.pfb/0/H/65536/0/0>
fontmap: /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/libertinus-type1/LibertinusSerif-Regular.pfb/0/H/65536/0/0 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/libertinus-type1/LibertinusSerif-Regular(Identity-H)
>
xdvipdfmx:fatal: Invalid font: -1 (0)

No output PDF file written.
```

How can I fix it?

---

I maybe know where the problem is. In TeXLive, there are two types of `Libertinus`, they are `type1` and `opentype`. The packages are `libertinus-type1` and `libertinus-fonts`

[image]

When I use `\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}`  to change font instead of `\setmainfont{LibertinusSerif-Regular.otf}`, xelatex will consider that I'm using the `type1` version font, not `.otf` version. Then the problem occurs.

Comment: In order to produce an XDV file you need to call `xelatex -no-pdf main`. Alternatively, try `xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -vv" main` so to get more diagnostic messages.

Comment: @egreg ok, I forgot to say in my question, I used `xelatex -no-pdf main`, and the `-vv` option's output I've post in the question

Comment: I may know the reason of this problem. This will be supplemented to my question

Comment: yes you sometimes need to exclude the type1 fonts from the search path. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/319946/2388

Comment: https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2021-April/046700.html

Comment: I solve the problem with David Carlisle's comment.