# XeCJK: Font NotoSansMonoCJKsc "Regular" causes error, "Bold" works

Tags: xetex, xecjk, chinese

## Table of contents

- The context
- The problem
- The question

## The context

I want to use the font "Noto Sans Mono CJK SC" for Chinese characters. The font can be downloaded at [this link in Github](https://github.com/notofonts/noto-cjk/blob/1c7ca85cb5195a3332e18c2b5cfe196ffb084e72/Sans/Mono/NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Regular.otf).

I know that it is possible to set the font for Chinese characters by using `\setCJKmainfont{...}` from the `xeCJK` package. See minimal working example below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setCJKmainfont{FandolKai}

\begin{document}
  \par \lipsum[1][1-3]
  \par 你好！
  \par \lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

By changing the name of the font in `setCJKmainfont`, I am also able to use `NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Bold`. See minimal working example below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setCJKmainfont{NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Bold}

\begin{document}
  \par \lipsum[1][1-3]
  \par 你好！
  \par \lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

## The problem

When I try to use font `NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Regular`. I get the error `xdvipdfmx:fatal: Invalid font: -1 (0)`.

The second and third code block below shows the output of `xelatex` when compiling the document. Note that the exit code is `1`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setCJKmainfont{NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Regular}

\begin{document}
  你好！
\end{document}
```

```sh
xelatex main.tex
echo "+++ Exit code: $?"
```

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021/GNU Guix) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/gnu/store/4rv29ip0aa5729kmm41mx0n7kszfvlfd-texlive-texmf-20210325/share/texmf
-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class

(/gnu/store/4rv29ip0aa5729kmm41mx0n7kszfvlfd-texlive-texmf-20210325/share/texmf
-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/gnu/store/4rv29ip0aa5729kmm41mx0n7kszfvlfd-texlive-texmf-20210325/share/texmf
-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.sty
(/gnu/store/4rv29ip0aa5729kmm41mx0n7kszfvlfd-texlive-texmf-20210325/share/texmf
-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/gnu/store/4rv29ip0aa5729kmm41mx0n7kszfvlfd-texlive-texmf-20210325/share/texmf
-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def (|extractbb --version)))
(/gnu/store/4rv29ip0aa5729kmm41mx0n7kszfvlfd-texlive-texmf-20210325/share/texmf
-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(/gnu/store/4rv29ip0aa5729kmm41mx0n7kszfvlfd-texlive-texmf-20210325/share/texmf
-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xtemplate/xtemplate.sty)
(/gnu/store/4rv29ip0aa5729kmm41mx0n7kszfvlfd-texlive-texmf-20210325/share/texmf
-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/gnu/store/4rv29ip0aa5729kmm41mx0n7kszfvlfd-texlive-texmf-20210325/share/texmf
-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-2020-10-01.sty
(/gnu/store/4rv29ip0aa5729kmm41mx0n7kszfvlfd-texlive-texmf-20210325/share/texmf
-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-generic.tex)))
(/gnu/store/4rv29ip0aa5729kmm41mx0n7kszfvlfd-texlive-texmf-20210325/share/texmf
-dist/tex/latex/ctex/ctexhook.sty)
(/gnu/store/4rv29ip0aa5729kmm41mx0n7kszfvlfd-texlive-texmf-20210325/share/texmf
-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/gnu/store/4rv29ip0aa5729kmm41mx0n7kszfvlfd-texlive-texmf-20210325/share/texmf
-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/gnu/store/4rv29ip0aa5729kmm41mx0n7kszfvlfd-texlive-texmf-20210325/share/texmf
-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/gnu/store/4rv29ip0aa5729kmm41mx0n7kszfvlfd-texlive-texmf-20210325/share/texmf
-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/gnu/store/4rv29ip0aa5729kmm41mx0n7kszfvlfd-texlive-texmf-20210325/share/texmf
-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.cfg)) (./main.aux)
(/gnu/store/4rv29ip0aa5729kmm41mx0n7kszfvlfd-texlive-texmf-20210325/share/texmf
-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd) [1] (./main.aux)
xdvipdfmx:fatal: Invalid font: -1 (0)

No output PDF file written.
 )
Error 256 (driver return code) generating output;
file main.pdf may not be valid.
Transcript written on main.log.
+++ Exit code: 1
```

## The question

I can compile the document when using `NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Bold` in `setCJKmainfont`, but not when using `NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Regular`. Why does this occur?

Both fonts `NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Regular.otf` and `NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Bold.otf` are installed (see below).

```sh
fc-list | grep '/\.fonts/' | sort
```

```
/home/rdrg/.fonts/FandolKai-Regular.otf: FandolKai:style=Regular
/home/rdrg/.fonts/NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Bold.otf: Noto Sans Mono CJK SC:style=Bold
/home/rdrg/.fonts/NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Regular.otf: Noto Sans Mono CJK SC:style=Regular
```

Comment: see the comments here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/612718/using-other-fonts-caused-xdvipdfmxfatal-invalid-font-1   -1 usually means it found the wrong font format. It can't be type1 for noto, but do you have the font in multiple formats?

Comment: I get no error in texlive 2023 xelatex from your example

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I found a solution thanks to one of your comments that I found in another question. I am still wondering why the command failed when I didn't specify the full path of the font.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by specifying the full path of the font (thanks to [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/612718/using-other-fonts-caused-xdvipdfmxfatal-invalid-font-1#comment1532428_612718) of David Carlisle).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setCJKmainfont[
  Path = {\string~/.fonts/},
  Extension = .otf
]{NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Regular}

\begin{document}
  \par \lipsum[1][1-3]
  \par 你好！
  \par \lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{document}
```

I'm still wondering why the compilation fails if I don't specify the full path of the font. XeLaTeX doesn't seem to be finding other formats in my system. As can be seen by the output of `strace` when trying to compile the document that caused the error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setCJKmainfont{NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Regular}

\begin{document}
  \par \lipsum[1][1-3]
  \par 你好！
  \par \lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{document}
```

```
$ strace --trace=openat xelatex main.tex 2>&1 | grep -v "= -1 ENOENT [(]No such file or directory[)]$" | grep -i 'notosansmonocjksc-regular'
```

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/rdrg/.guix-home/profile/share/fonts/opentype/NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Regular.otf", O_RDONLY) = 5
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/rdrg/.fonts/NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Regular.otf", O_RDONLY) = 5
```

Comment: oh it is type 1, try running with --nopdf so you get .xdv them strace xdvipdfmx running on that